# Cannot resolve method setEmptyView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-widget

I am trying to set a TextView as an empty view if my recyclerView doesn't load, and I cannot get setEmptyView to work. It says cannot resolve method setEmptyView. This is the code:

```
    RecyclerView recyclerViewUser1 = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_red_room1);
    emptyStateTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    recyclerViewUser1.setEmptyView(emptyStateTextView);
```

I am in a Fragment, could that be why?

Comment: `setEmptyView` is used by `AdapterView`, not `RecyclerView`

Comment: please put your xml code of the recycler view

Answer (score 3):

RecyclerView not support setEmptyView. Can use this class.

```
public class RecyclerViewEmptyView extends RecyclerView {
    private View emptyView;

    private AdapterDataObserver emptyObserver = new AdapterDataObserver() {


        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            Adapter<?> adapter =  getAdapter();
            if(adapter != null && emptyView != null) {
                if(adapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    RecyclerViewEmptySupport.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    RecyclerViewEmptySupport.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

        }
    };

    public RecyclerViewEmptySupport(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RecyclerViewEmptySupport(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RecyclerViewEmptySupport(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(adapter != null) {
            adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(emptyObserver);
        }

        emptyObserver.onChanged();
    }

    public void setEmptyView(View emptyView) {
        this.emptyView = emptyView;
    }
}
```

Or you can

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="No Data Available" />
```

Java code :

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private TextView emptyView;

// ...

recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
emptyView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

// ...

if (dataset.isEmpty()) {
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else {
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to set your `emptyView` in xml to `android:visibility="gone"`.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="There is no item" />
```

Second, you have to set the visibility of recyclerview to gone if the dataset that you retrieved is empty.

```
private RecyclerView recyclerViewUser1 ;
private TextView emptyStateTextView ;

// ...

recyclerViewUser1 = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_red_room1);
emptyStateTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

// ...

if (dataset.isEmpty()) {
    recyclerViewUser1 .setVisibility(View.GONE);
    emptyStateTextView .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else {
    recyclerViewUser1 .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    emptyStateTextView .setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```